# Tristate driver I/O for analog signals

Tags: analog, output, input, tri-state

In FPGAs a tristate drive is used to convert a pin from an input to an output or vice versa.  Now this works only in digital circuits.  Is there a way how you could obtain the same functionality of the circuit but that it is able to work for analogue signals?

Comment: Yes, switch between diodes. But you better tell us why are you asking this.

Comment: Analog switches. But you should explain your question better

Comment: are you sure that this is true? `In FPGAs a tristate drive is used to convert a pin from an input to an output` ... it strikes me as being incorrect, but I am not very familiar with FPGAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, logic-controlled analog switches exist; they are normally called ["Transmission Gates"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_gate). You can get chips that have individually-controlled gates, or chips that have them grouped to form analog multiplexers.

Comment: I've never seen them called "transmission gates" when buying them as chips. For example, Analog Devices calls them [analog switches](http://www.analog.com/en/products/switches-multiplexers/analog-switches-multiplexers.html) and so does [TI](http://www.ti.com/switches-multiplexers/analog/overview.html).

Comment: @ThePhoton: Maybe you're right. They're called transmission gates in the context of CMOS design, to distinguish them from other kinds of gates that have gain. But it's the same idea in SSI/MSI form.